# Kumuluz EE: How to secure GraphQL endpoint?

Tags: java, graphql, kumuluzee

Does anyone know how to secure a GraphQL Endpoint that is made with KumuluzEE graphQL? Apparently there is support by KumuluzEE security, but I can't find how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/kumuluz/kumuluzee-samples/tree/master/kumuluzee-graphql-jpa-security) for using KumuluzEE Security with the KumuluzEE GraphQL extension.